# How to continue developing with a React Native Project with xCode?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, xcodeproj

I have complete my first little application with React Native.

Now I want to change some styles or the splash screen on their native platform, where is the generated code for these platforms? I checked the `ios` and `android` folder, but I just can't find the place of code.

For example, in xCode, I think most of code is stay in `main.jsbundle` file. but I don't know how to open it. Moreover, is it possible to continue with Swift language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where is the generated code for these platforms?

This is the point, React Native will not compile to ObjectiveC or Java. ReactNative is a set of Native Components which are controlled by JS over the NativeBridge.

Your whole application Logic lives in JS and talks to the native UI layer via the bridge.

Some links on this
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html

How to write your own native components and use control them with js
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for the LaunchScreen.xib in your ios folder. You can then edit it from XCode.

You could also create a new StoryBoard file and make it your default splash screen by going to `YourApp > General > App Icons and Launch Images > Launch Screen File` and by selecting your new Storyboard.

Finally, maybe [this could help you](https://gist.github.com/boopathi/27d21956fefcb5b168fe) if you want to add some Swift to your React Native project.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have found the launch screen, but where are the other pages and containers?

Comment: As far as I know, you won't be able to access them from XCode. Maybe this will help you understand how React Native actually works: https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial
(at the beginning, just before the "Hello World JSX" section)